# Syntax error on token "enum", delete this token

Tags: java

hello guy's I'm beginner in java  
i have a problem how can i fix this error? 
i am learning java programming.
 and i cant delete this token because my lesson is "enum" subject.  
sorry for my enlish .

[image]

thank you

Comment: Did you try deleting the token, as the error message said? What were you trying to accomplish with it? (Note that we can't see any text that's underneath the pop-up. Your question would be better with everything posted as *text*, and just tell us that the pop-up appears over the token "enum".)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EnumExample {
    public enum Alphabets {
        A, B, C, D
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(Alphabets.A);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to declare an enum, then that's not how you declare it.

try something like below:

```
enum DemoEnum {
  DEMO1,
  DEMO2
};
```

Other than that, your question is incomplete and doesn't make much sense. I would suggest correcting it if this does not answer your doubt.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;


public class EnumExample {
 public enum Alphabets{ 
  A,
  B, 
  C, 
  D
 }

 
 
 
 
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println(Alphabets.A);

 }

}
it doesn't work  still have problem and im sorry for my english

Comment: See, there is nothing wrong with the Java code. Your problem is with the IDE. Try using other IDE like IntelliJ.